# How to manage layout with checkbox in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

I have multiple layout in a xml file and I want with checkbox from another xml file to show or hide the layout who is checked or unchecked.

This is the main layout and I want to show or hide Linearlayout1 or LinearLayout2 etc.

So I click on the button "Layout" and I can activate or desactivate layout by checking a checkbox

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Layout 1" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Layout 2" />

</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Layout 3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:text="Layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With the java code:

```
package com.dlayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button button4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.dlayout.Checkbox"));

        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    startActivity(new Intent("com.dlayout.Checkbox"));

}



}
```

and my other xml file with the checkbox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox1" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox2" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my java code of my checkbox class:

```
package com.dlayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Checkbox extends MainActivity {

CheckBox cb1;
CheckBox cb2;
CheckBox cb3;
LinearLayout linearLayout1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkbox);


    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
}

// *******************I know, this code is not working***************
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view){
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view) .isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.cb1:
        if (checked)

           //linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            else
                //linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
    case R.id.cb2:
        if (checked)
            //LinearLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            else
            //linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
    case R.id.cb3:
        if (checked)
            //LinearLayout3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            else
                //linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
    //**************************************************************

    }

}
}
```

So when the checkbox1 is checked, the layout1 is visible when isn't, the layout1 is invisible.

Can you suggest me any ideas?

Comment: If the other checkbox xml is merely for hiding/unhiding the main layout then you can use SharedPreferences and can easily check if the checkbox is checked or not and hence can hide/unhide your main xml.

Comment: Is this all within the same `Activity` or are you checking a box then pressing a button and going to a different `Activity` where you want to show/hide this `layout`?

Comment: @codeMagic It's was from a different activity but I'm kinda new in android programmation. So if you can tell me the best way to do it, I'll appreciate that.

Comment: I posted an answer but after reading your comment, I'm not convinced I know what you're trying to do. If you could explain your situation a little better then I may be able to give a more precise answer.

Comment: @codeMagic I edit my post with more information

Answer (score 0):

If this is all in one `Activity` and you want to show/hide a `layout` from a different xml file then you will first need to `inflate` that `layout` so you have a reference to it. Then you can use a `checkChangedListener` to know when the `Checkbox` state has changed and change the `visibility` of that `layout`.

If it is going from one `Activity` to another then you can simply check the state of the `CheckBox` in your `onClick()` and send some type of `extra` data in your `intent` to check in the next `Activity` to know to show/hide the `layout`.